# Docker Swarm - PHP-FPM not working with Nginx running on manager

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I've build a cluster (1 manager, 4 workers). Only the manager has a public IP address, workers and the manager are on a private network.

I tried to build a webserver (Nginx + PHP-FPM) with Docker Swarm. So I set the Nginx container on the manager, so I can request it from outside the private network. If I do that, the container get a `upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream` error while requesting a PHP file. If I run it on a worker node, everything works fine, but the Nginx isn't accessible from outside the private network (I can only request with curl on the manager or every worker).

Do you guys have any idea ? I really don't understand why running Nginx on the manager makes PHP-FPM timed out. Thanks !

Here the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'
services: 
  nginx:
    image: arm32v5/nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver_nginx
    ports: 
      - 80:80
    volumes: 
      - /media/storage/webserver/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /media/storage/webserver/nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
      - /media/storage/www:/var/www
    links: 
      - php
    networks:
      - webserver
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - "node.role==manager"

  php:
    image: arm32v5/php:7.4-fpm
    container_name: webserver_php
    volumes:
      - /media/storage/www:/var/www
      - /media/storage/webserver/nginx/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
    networks:
      - webserver
    links:
      - nginx
    ports:
      - 9000:9000

networks:
  webserver:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

Nginx configuration:

```
user                       nginx;
worker_processes           1;

error_log                  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections     1024;
}

http {
    include                /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type           application/octet-stream;
    
    log_format             main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log             /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
    
    sendfile               on;
    keepalive_timeout      65;
    server_tokens          off;

    server {
        listen 80;
        
        error_page         500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        
        location / {
            index          index.php index.html index.htm;
            root           /var/www/;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /var/www/;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar kind of issue and the solution was to use the `docker service name` in upstream.

Here is my setup

- 3 EC2 with Docker Swarm
- 1 Swarm Manager ( Nginx proxy deployed )
- 2 Swarm Worker  (Frontend + backend deployed)

**Flow**
Browser ->> Nginx-proxy ->> React-frontend (Nginx) ->> Go-backend

#### nginx.conf

```
http {
    
    upstream allbackend {
        server exam105_frontend:8080; #FrontEnd Service Name
    } 

    server {
        listen 80;

        location / {

              proxy_pass http://allbackend;
        }
    }

}
```

#### Docker Swarm Services

[image]

#### AWS Note:

Remember to open port **80** publicly and **8080** (or whatever port number you are using) for internal communication in Security Group of your AWS setup, otherwise you won't be able to access the service.